# Probelm with flutter_facebook_plugin on flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

When I add `flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.1` on pubspec.yaml on flutter project. The following error came:
`Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:52661/75sNfQnMaEw=/ws`

Comment: are you using any emulator and is it Q os ?

Comment: No I am using physical device with android 5.1 ie. Lolipop

Comment: did solve the problem? @leo-boy